# problem with connect presto to hive-hadoop3

Tags: hadoop, hive, presto

I have hadoop 3.1.2 and hive 3.1.2 on a cluster and I want to connect to hive with presto-server-0.265.1.
I have just one catalog file in /opt/presto/etc/catalog as hive.properties here is:

```
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://192.168.49.13:9083
```

The presto service run but it can not connect to hive because I use hadoop3 and when I change hive.properties,presto service can not run.

how can I connect to hadoop3?

Update:

it wasn't about hadoop. hive metastore was not installed correctly so presto had problem to connect hive metastore